# Query node with multiple keys firebase iOS / Queryequal with array of key in firebase IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have books node and users node, users node has favorite books, now I wanted to get the favorite books and display them.

so my fetch is like get current user->get favorite books => gives list now how to get this list of books from the books node using firebase/firebasui

Comment: In general, it's best practice to include your Firebase structure as well as the code you have tried so far as text. You can get your structure via the Firebase console->Three dots on right->Export JSON. In your question, you mention wanting to get the favorite books and display them. Which favorite books, ALL of them? The most popular? One users books? It help us to answer when the question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it this way. Bind the collection view directly to the favorite array then for each snapshot call the book node then configure the cell

```
let ref = firebaseRef?.child("users").child(userUid!).child("FavBooks").queryOrderedByKey()

self.datasrc = (savedCollectionView?.bind(to: ref!){ collectionView, IndexPath, snap in
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: IndexPath)

  let bookRef = self.firebaseRef?.child("Books").child(snap.key).queryOrderedByKey()
  bookRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
  //configure cell
  })
  return cell
})!
```

Comment: This is going to be problematic as the cell will be returned before the data is returned from Firebase; most of the time the cell will be blank. Code is much faster than the internet so the *return cell* call will execute before the observe closure has a change to populate the cell.

Comment: you are correct, is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: yeah - don't do that. lol. All kidding aside, you should populate your tableView or collectionView dataSource first - possibly in the viewDidLoad function, then once the dataSource (typically an array) is fully populated within the firebase closure, call tableView.reloadData() which will then pull data from the local array (dataSource). If you want to keep your data live, adding observers to Firebase for .childAdded events would in turn, add data to the dataSource from the newly added Firebase data and then tableView.reloadData() to update the UI